# Graph visualization (boost graph)

Tags: c++, graph, plot, visualization, boost-graph

I have C++ program using boost graph library. I wonder if there is any way to visualize the graph (nodes and optionally edges) following a certain position values contained in nodes. Please look the examples of the image bellow to understand what I want to visualise:
http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/647608graphViz.png

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're in luck.

Boost graph can serialize to and deserialize from the `dot` language (which is the language used by [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org)). There are several examples in the (free) Boost Graph Library book and on the site.

See e.g.: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/graph/doc/write-graphviz.html

If you take the output of the sample on the *previous webpage* and run

```
dot -Tpng dot > test.png
```

You'll get *something like* the following picture:

[image]

Here is a direct link to an [example using dynamic properties](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/graph/example/graphviz.cpp)

Comment: That's awesome, thanks for you answer, I'll wee that.
But is it possible to visualise a graph using edges and vertices of type setS (not vecS) ? Because I see that in all examples of graphviz the graph use vecS (which have an index).

Comment: Since my graph use setS for vertex, I have to either provide a vertex_index property map for my graph, or give an explicit vertex_id
argument to write_graphviz, otherwise write_graphviz will not work.
Can you give me a very simple example of how to provide a vertex_index property map for my graph, or give an explicit vertex_id argument to write_graphviz ?
My graph is defined as:
typedef adjacency_list<setS, setS, undirectedS, NodeData, EdgeData> Graph;
Where NodeData and EdgeData are structures.